# In WPF is the contents of ListBox the same as its bound ItemsSource? and how do I seperate them?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a ListBox with its ItemsSource bound to some UserControl-s and shown based on their current states(IsVisible)
Here is the code

```
<ListBox x:Name="sidebarList" Margin="0,0,10,10" ItemsSource="{Binding Modules, Mode=TwoWay}">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Margin="0 5 0 5" Visibility="{Binding IsVisible, Mode=TwoWay}">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" FontWeight="Bold" />
                                <TextBlock Margin="0 5 0 0" MaxWidth="200" Foreground="Gray" Text="{Binding Detail}" 
                                           TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow">
                                </TextBlock>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsVisible}" Value="Collapsed">
                                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                </ListBox>
```

And now I'm trying to only get "`IsVisible`"/selected parts when a button is pressed. As of right now, the ListBox actually contains every option but just showing the `IsVisible` ones(at least that's what I think).

How do I only get the selected options? I have tried to use a new List with the same type as the UserControl-s type(which I placed in app.xaml.cs to call from anywhere) and add to that list when their state changes to `IsVisible`

but the List doesn't show up in my classes where I check them.

Comment: If my understanding is correct, are you trying to get only visible and selected items in the listbox in code behind?

Comment: I think so, I'm also not sure what exactly I need. but if you know some ways to get the chosen items. I would appreciate it if you tell me how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like what you really need is a view-model. Bind your Listbox to a view model that has an observable collection that only shows view-models of the items you want to present.

I can give you a more "correct" answer about how to do it with style/data-triggers but you should really just learn about MVVM and use a view-model to simplify.